# Calculating Profit in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, calculator

I am having trouble calculating the profit of a stock in excel.

[image: Image of excel spreadsheet]

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/KQN0f

Comment: You are asking a Profit question, not an Excel question. Not homework, eh hem... Google profit formula.

Comment: Well... In cell L37 write down this **=(J37*H37)-D37** , then drag the right corner of the cell to the end of the table to copy the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Are you struggling with the maths or how to do the maths with Excel?

```
Current price - original price = profit per share
```

Multiply by number of shares on one side of the equal sign to see the total profit.

Comment: Both lol. They didn't teach me math in the Marines